# Facing issue to group by and sum the records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am facing an issue to group by the the following records. I tried many things but nothing is working.

I want to group by the record according to trainer and province and also want to sum the total_training_count column and total_amount column according to trainer and province.

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| trai_name | trainer_province | no_of_tp_assigned | no_of_thd_assigned | total_training_count | total_amount |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|         3 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |      9000.00 |
|         3 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |     16000.00 |
|         3 |                5 |                 0 |                  1 |                    1 |     14000.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |     13000.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |      9000.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |      9000.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                    1 |     10280.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 0 |                  1 |                    1 |     18000.00 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

I want my query result like in given table:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| trai_name | trainer_province | no_of_tp_assigned | no_of_thd_assigned | total_training_count | total_amount |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|         3 |                5 |                 2 |                  1 |                    3 |        39000 |
|        11 |                5 |                 5 |                  1 |                    6 |     46280.00 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT
  vtt.trai_name,
  vtt.trainer_province,
  vtt.no_of_tp_assigned,
  vtt.no_of_thd_assigned,
  SUM(vtt.total_training_count),
  SUM(vtt.total_amount) total_amount
FROM v_test_tt vtt
  GROUP BY
  vtt.trai_name,
  vtt.trainer_province
```

After the query execution it did not show the right data in the column no 3,4 and 5:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+
| trai_name | trainer_province | no_of_tp_assigned | no_of_thd_assigned | SUM(vtt.total_training_count) | total_amount |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+
|         3 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                             3 |     39000.00 |
|        11 |                5 |                 1 |                  0 |                             5 |     59280.00 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question - there is neither a SUM nor a GROUP BY in your query.

Comment: It looks like you can just use `GROUP BY trai_name, trainer_province` at the end, then `SUM()` on the relevant columns.

Comment: Start off with `SELECT trai_name, SUM(no_of_tp_assigned)` and then get that working. Then add new `SUM()` columns one by one.

Comment: @halfer SELECT
  vtt.trai_name,
  vtt.trainer_province,
  vtt.no_of_tp_assigned,
  vtt.no_of_thd_assigned,
  SUM(vtt.total_training_count),
  SUM(vtt.total_amount) total_amount
FROM v_test_tt vtt
  GROUP BY
  vtt.trai_name,
  vtt.trainer_province

Comment: @halfer i did but it did not club the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT vtt.trai_name,
       MIN(vtt.trainer_province),
       SUM(vtt.no_of_tp_assigned),
       SUM(vtt.no_of_thd_assigned),
       SUM(vtt.total_training_count),
       SUM(vtt.total_amount) total_amount
  FROM v_test_tt vtt
 GROUP BY vtt.trai_name;
```

Comment: it work but it did not show right data in the col no 3 and 4.

Comment: @AdilRiaz, 4th column `no_of_thd_assigned` seems correct to me. Please explain the logic behind 3rd column to be 5 for trai_name 11.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: I think "no" is short for "number". So maybe this should be `COUNT` rather than `SUM`? Perhaps Adil can try it.

Comment: However, that would mean it would be no_of_tp_assigned=3 for trai_name=3, which the expected result says is wrong.

Comment: @halfer thats my concern

Comment: @AdilRiaz: in that case, your expected results seem to be wrong, and you need to correct them. I have suggested what I think they mean - it would be most helpful if you could comment on whether I am right, and make any clarifications/corrections to the main post.

Comment: @AdilRiaz: I've seen your edit, but it does not address the problem at hand. For trainer 3, `no_of_tp_assigned` should either be 2 (because there are 2 non-zero values) or it should be 3 (because there are 3 values). Similarly for trainer 11, the correct result should either be 4 or 5, depending on what logic is applied.

Comment: Since different logic appears to have been applied to these expectations, a clarification from you is in order.

Comment: @halfer i have differing set of result in the first table  now tell me what is final query to resolved this issue to group by the record of trainer 3 and 4.

Comment: Could you read my comments again? The logic to count things is inconsistent between the two trainers, and I think this needs to be resolved before someone can indicate how to solve it.